# Visual Studio IDE 2022 Text Editor Issue

Tags: c#, visual-studio, razor, intellisense, text-editor

I need help figuring out what's happening with my Text Editor in Visual Studio IDE 2022. When I type in the editor some actions with @ directive, e.g. in a div or input, the intellisense shows suggestions, which is fine, but then the suggestions do not go away after selection. The only solution I have is to restart the IDE but the issues comes up again. Please see the attached image. Any ideas on how to solve this?

[image]

Comment: In a Razor page? I think all sorts of stuff is still wonky with all that; have you reported as a bug to MS? Help menu (i think) in VS.. Send Feedback.. Report a problem..

Comment: @Cauis Jard: Will report it as abug. I thought there was something wrong with my configuration. Thank you